# getting default google Recaptcha red theme

Tags: javascript, captcha, recaptcha

I have used google ReCaptcha in one my application just by seeing the following steps over here at https://www.google.com/recaptcha.

I have added **Client side Integration** with

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>

<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="MY_PUBLIC_KEY"></div>
```

Captcha is working fine but I am getting the following default theme as shown in the picture below

[image]

Actually I am looking to get the red theme captcha like as shown below

[image]

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

Comment: Did you try explicitly setting the theme attribute? (Refer: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#config)  Attribute: `data-theme="dark"`

Comment: I am not setting any theme in my application....do I need to do anything to get the red theme

Comment: First image is google recaptcha version 2 and second image is version 1.

Comment: what is the difference between those two versions @VigneswaranMarimuthu

Comment: @AlexMan As far as i know, they have entirely changed the API's and even the way user authenticates captcha challenge. Have a look at their demo video :)

Comment: so cant we get the theme also

Comment: @AlexMan I am not sure it will result in the same Red theme as that is an old version of recaptcha. Still you can try it. `<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="MY_PUBLIC_KEY" data-theme="dark"></div>`

Comment: @RohitBatra `data-theme="dark"` make it dark instead of white but the theme is same :)

Comment: @AlexMan So I don't think you can get that Red theme. As there's no other configuration options in their API

Answer (score 0):

Google has a new version for reCAPTCHA.
The first image you attached is version 2 while the red image is version 1.

Have a look a the documentation of version 1 - you can use `theme: 'red'` property.

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/customization

Answer (score 0):

In most cases it's **simple click**, but if **Google’s risk analysis** still can’t be sure you’re human, a second prompt will appear.

The reason your getting the second prompt may be [This](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-integrate-no-captcha-recaptcha-in-your-website--cms-23024) . Still if you want to change the color you can refer [Change Color](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq)